# How to display multi level menubar in djangoCMS

Tags: django-cms

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache %}
{% for child in children %}
<li class="{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}
    {% if child.selected %} active{% endif %}
    {% if child.chil`enter code here`dren %} dropdown{% endif %}">
    {% if child.children %}
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            {{ child.get_menu_title }} <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive    extra_active template "" "" child %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}"><span>{{ child.get_menu_title }}</span></a>
    {% endif %}
</li>

{% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is code of menu.html in djagocms project.

Could anyone help to me, how we can display multi level menubar in djangocms. like:

```
----------
> main menu
> --sub menu
> --sub menu
> ----sub menu
> ----sub menu
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a multilevel menu which I include in my base template like so;

```
        <ul class="dropdown">
            {% show_menu 1 100 100 100 "partials/navigation.html" %}
        </ul>
```

That custom template looks like this;

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags cache cms_page %}

{% for child in children %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
        {% if child.children and child.level <= 4 %}
            <ul>
            {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template '' '' child %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This renders out a multilevel menu which shows all children of a page as a new list.